# My top bar has partially disappeared

Tags: support, design

This is on Chrome and a hard reset does not resolve the problem. It also happens on meta and on other network sites.

[image: top bar gone]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This started happening with an update to Adblocker Plus. Disabling Adblocker will fix the issue.

See [Image of Stack Exchange button is blocked by Adblock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225831/image-of-stack-exchange-button-is-blocked-by-adblock) on Stack Overflow Meta.

> One of the filter lists that ABP installs by default (Fanboy Social) blocks all images whose filename starts with "share-sprite-", and the sprite file that contains the button's logo has such a file name.

Comment: Note: I have whitelisted ABP for `*.stackexchange.com`, and all I see are lovely community ads.

Comment: @fredley that's what I've done too.

Answer (score 6):

Updating the Fanboy Annoyances/Social Blocking filter list in your ad blocker extension should fix the issue. [Related post in the EasyList forums](http://forums.lanik.us/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=16078).

[image]

Comment: Yep it works. I've added a picture to show the steps to take

Comment: @Robotnik my version of ABP looks completely different to yours

Comment: @shanodin - really? Wait.. Firefox or chrome?

Comment: @Robotnik Chrome

Comment: @shanodin Tharr's ya problem. My screenshots are from Firefox :). If the steps are different it might be worth adding some screenshots from Chrome?